# row is missing images

Tags: html, css

first row have images. the second row have long space and one image at the end. the third row have images. image are in different size.

i tried width under 10%. i move images around. height work, but when readjusting the browser the image will not move.

```css
.row>.column {
  padding: 5%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 5%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="image/image0.jpg" onclick="openLightbox();toSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow preview">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="image/image1.jpg" onclick="openLightbox();toSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow preview">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="image/image2.jpg" onclick="openLightbox();toSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow preview">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="image/image3.jpg" onclick="openLightbox();toSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow preview">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="image/image4.jpg" onclick="openLightbox();toSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

first row have images. the second row have long space and one image at the end. the third row have images. image are in different size.

Comment: can you please tell wha you want us to check. your question is not and it is giving js error.

Comment: There is only one row there Tom

Comment: Please edit your question and put in all the row, as DrWaky mentioned, there is only 1 row. And also, what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you check out css grids. It's the best way to do grid-based positioning: https://gridbyexample.com/

Comment: I don't know the exact purpose of this code, but as a offtopic comment, please use `<table>` for tabular data...

Comment: Also, w.r.t your last comment, I see no attempt to give all images identical sizes, so if they are different, they will come out different.

Comment: it was leaving a big gap between the picture after the first row, but i found the answer. the picture i have on my page was different size. i had to readjust the picture around. thanks everybody for you're answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help.